# Should we use require_once in a module's registration.php?

Tags: require-once

I am of the opinion that using require_once in registration.php is not ok and possibly against Magento coding standards.

Am I right or wrong?

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);

require_once(BP.'/lib/internal/SomeModule/src/somemodule/autoload.php');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `composer require` the package you want.

For example: install aws-sdk for magento

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php
```

For your custom extension, you can edit to your `composer.json` for other people to use.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It's not a custom extension, but rather a bunch of classes and libraries, and only for private use. Are you saying we should convert it to a custom extension and install it via composer, which will then make sure everything is autoloaded?

Comment: @MichaelMussulis Yes, I think that converting to a custom extension or libraries of composer

Comment: it worked. Thanks for the advice.